# How to get the section title in forms to go to a specific planner bucket with power automate?

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, microsoft-planner, ms-forms

I currently have a MS Form that has sections that contain multiple choice answers. The sections are broken into academics, labs, cbts etc. Each answer selected in those will create a task in planner. I am trying to figure out how each section will go into a different bucket without making it its own question.
See below for examples of the form and where I am trying to find the correct input for the buckets. [image: PowerAutomate bucket insert][image: MS Form section example]

I only currently know how to select a predetermined bucket vs finding the correct expression to get it to know which bucket to go into from the section the answer was selected from.